# Not getting intellisense to CopyToDataTable Method

Tags: linq-to-sql

Im not able to  add System.data.datatableextensions as reference and also not the method CopyTODataTable is not getting recognised.

Thanks and regards,
Veena

Answer (score 0):

If you cant add a reference to the assembly, you will never get the intellisense or be able to compile the code.

IOW, you HAVE to add that reference.

Why can you not add that reference?